# Writing file using FileSystem to S3 (Scala)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hdfs

I'm using scala , and trying to write file with string content, 
to S3.
I've tried to do that with FileSystem , 
but I getting an error of:
"Wrong FS: s3a"

```scala
    val content = "blabla"
    val fs = FileSystem.get(spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration)
    val s3Path: Path = new Path("s3a://bucket/ha/fileTest.txt")
    val localPath= new Path("/tmp/fileTest.txt")
    val os = fs.create(localPath)
    os.write(content.getBytes)
    fs.copyFromLocalFile(localPath,s3Path)
```

and i'm getting an error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong FS: s3a://...txt, expected: file:///
```

What is wrong?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

you need to ask for the specific filesystem for that scheme, then you can create a text file directly on the remote system.

```scala
val s3Path: Path = new Path("s3a://bucket/ha/fileTest.txt")
val fs = s3Path.getFilesystem(spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration)
val os = fs.create(s3Path, true)
os.write("hi".getBytes)
os.close
```

There's no need to write locally and upload; the s3a connector will buffer and upload as needed

Comment: This does not address problems with the authors code, it provides an alternative approach for writing to S3. The question .involves using multiple FS types (Local / S3), and copying between them

Comment: Maybe, but his code: writes to a local file then uploads to S3 via the S3A connector. Which by defaul) writes to a local temp dir until the amount of data written is > than a certain threshold (64MB) when it kicks off to incremental multipart uploads, I'm confident, as the author of most of that S3A stream write code (HADOOP-13560) my recommendation is the faster codepath for all file sizes.